# "Angel and demon" versus "demon and angel"

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

The equivalent of the Italian *bianco e nero* (literally, *white and black*) is *black and white*. What is the equivalent, idiomatic phrase for *angelo e demone* (literally, *angel and demon*)?

I looked at the CoCA, and I found the following:

- *Angel and demon*, 0 sentences
- *Angel and demons*, 0 sentences
- *Angels and demon*, 0 sentences
- *Angels and demons*, 38 sentences
- *Demon and angel*, 1 sentence
- *Demon and angels*, 0 sentences
- *Demons and angel*, 0 sentences
- *Demons and angels*, 7 sentences

I am looking for a phrase to use when describing a person's character using opposites, as in "She is an angel and a demon, passionate and cold, sweet and bitter."

Comment: What exactly are you asking about here? Whether and why certain word-pairs show a significant preference for one sequence rather than the other? Or an alternative to *angels and demons*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I took the question to be asking about the order; which sounds more natural coming first in sequence, *angel* or *demon*. I think in general I agree with the search results, the plural *angels and demons* sounds more natural in isolation, [but then again it's also the title of a book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angels_&_Demons). But in the example with the list of characteristics, I think you pick whichever order goes with the rest of your list. Since you

Comment: have *passionate* and *sweet* as the first items, so should *angel* be. I also think you either put the good or bad attributes first based on which you are trying to emphasize; is she *more* angel or *more* demon?

Comment: @Wendikidd: There are probably several different (sometimes conflicting) principles involved, though I imagine for most pairings and most speakers the sequence is primarily determined by *precedent* (what they've heard before). Having said that, I think "most important first" is probably the most common underlying principle. It's noticeable that when most parents reference [their grown-up child] **and** [his/her life-partner], they invariably name *their own child **first***.

Comment: ...I'm sure if forced to make a choice, the average person would say ***angels** are more important [or, "better"] than **demons***.

Comment: @kiamlaluno In the plural, put the good guys [first](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=angels+and+demons%2Bangels+and+devils%2Cdemons+and+angels%2Bdevils+and+angels&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28angels%20and%20demons%20%2B%20angels%20and%20devils%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28demons%20and%20angels%20%2B%20devils%20and%20angels%29%3B%2Cc0). But in your context, put the quality you think is more important last, since the *(both) X and Y* construction emphasizes the contrasting quality.

Comment: @FumbleFingers By itself, I agree; but kiam's sentence puts the emphasis on the contrast, which turns it around. "She is passionate AND COLD".

Comment: @StoneyB Hmm. I would agree if *but* were being used rather than *and* (She is passionate *BUT* cold...). With *and*, the qualities seem to be referenced more equally to me, with a slight emphasis on the one mentioned first. I suppose because to me *and* means "both these things" whereas *but* means "this, but strangely also this." As in, you're using the first quality simply to emphasize the strangeness of the second. But I don't see this in the *and* version, personally.

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, we're getting well into "creative writing/LitCrit" territory here. And I personally would need an awful lot more context before I could even *begin* to form an impression of someone being simultaneously *passionate **and** cold*. But all that's by the by - my first comment/question still stands, and if it's not addressed relatively soon I'll probably closevote as "Unclear".

Comment: When you pair arbitrary words in English, if one begins with a sonorant, it tends to come first.  (*Angel* begins with a sonorant, and *demon* does not.)  This is only one possible factor, of course.

Comment: @snailboat That's fascinating - where'd you run across it?

Comment: @StoneyB That would be *World Order* by Cooper & Ross, 1975.

Comment: @snailboat: Fascinating indeed! My first thought was that pairings like *cat and mouse, bangers and mash* don't fit that principle, but they're presumably influenced more by the "primary" principle (*most important/most positively perceived* first).

Comment: @snailboat Thanks! I found it at once -- on [John Lawler's website](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/worldorder.pdf).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed, the sound is probably a secondary factor.

Comment: In the absence of any reaction from OP to my first comment, I'm closevoting as Off Topic. As it stands, it looks to me like proofreading/writing advice, rather than a general enquiry about the preferred order for common word-pairs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is asking whenever an English native speaker would say _angel and demon_ or _demon and angel_ proofreading? It would not be acceptable if I didn't identified a specific source of concern, but I did identify the source of concern. Plus, the sentence I wrote is just to give a context; I didn't write "please help me write this sentence in a better way." If that were the case, I would not even said I was not sure about _demon and angel_ or _angel and demon_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Forgive me if I'm being obtuse here, but I *still* don't know whether you're asking about the possibility of a preferred order for the specific pairing of ***angels*** and ***demons*** (which I maintain is OT), or whether you're asking for a definitive set of rules for those word pairs that *do* have a preferred order (which quite frankly I think is Too Broad for ELU).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Isn’t it possible he’s primarily just “looking for a phrase to use when describing a person’s character using opposites”?

Comment: Hopefully you noticed that “Angels and Demons” is the name of a [book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angels_&_Demons) that has also been made into a [movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angels_&_Demons_(film)). I think that will skew the results of your corpus comparisons.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Yes, that is what I am asking. Since the preferred order is _black and white_, and not _white and black_, I was wondering what would be be more idiomatic phrase for _devil and angel_.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Yes, [Angels and Demons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angels_%26_Demons_\(disambiguation\)) is used in more contexts, as title.

Comment: I think the phrase is well written the way you have it. It is clear what you mean. I don't think there's any set phrase or idiom for this, though the [girl with the curl](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/173916) and various versions of [hot and cold](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/run_hot_and_cold) come to mind.

Comment: It does seem better to have the positive element first in every pair, but I'm not really sure why.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this](http://bit.ly/1gpq4yi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While one may be more euphonic than the other (as people have been discussing in comments on the question), you ask which is the "idiomatic phrase". Unlike *black and white*, neither *angel and demon* nor *demon and angel* is idiomatic in English.

Comment: Correct. The proper meaning of "idiom" is that it is some phrase with a non-compositional meaning, like "kick the bucket". The usual way to say something, like "black and white" rather than "white and black", isn't an idiom.

Comment: @Kaz, "Is idiomatic" does not mean the same thing as "is an idiom". The first meaning of *idiomatic* in Wiktionary is "Pertaining or conforming to the mode of expression characteristic of a language." So something can be idiomatic (or not) without it being an idiom.

Comment: @Martha That is just how some non-users of dictionaries misuse the word *idiomatic* and *idiom* (and some dictionaries strive to catch up with those who don't use them).

Comment: @Kaz According to the OED, "idiom" occurs in the sense of "the specific character or individuality of a language; the manner of expression considered natural to or distinctive of a language" as early as 1573, in the narrower sense of "the distinctive form of speech of a particular people or country" since 1593 or earlier, and the sense to which you refer, of "a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from the meanings of the individual words" only later, around 1631.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung So, people who are still using it wrong should get out of the 1500's and catch up with the 1600's.

Comment: @Kaz That, or (by the logic of your previous statement): dictionaries in the 1600s never should have striven to catch up with the usage you prefer. I don't think you can have it both ways.